# opensource standalone substitute for oracle 11g R2

Tags: unit-testing, junit, oracle11g, derby

I have a large test code base for a project.
The junit test cases primarily use oracle DB for unit testing.
We are trying to make the unit test more local so that multiple developers can create test specific data on their local machines and the test cases/development are faster to complete.

Our current database contains multiple schemas, synonyms and stored procedures.

We are trying to identify a DB such as

> HSQL/Oracle Berkley DB/Derby DB

so that we can recreate the oracle like DB structure and continue with testing without any changes to test cases [ since the same test cases also run on our cruisecontrol]

The primary goal is to be able to have a local DB setup that can replicate the prod like DB structure with out any change to the current test suite.

Is there any DB (which can create DB locally on file system)?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Ayusman

Comment: Is there a reason that you're not considering installing a local Oracle instance for each developer (potentially XE)?  Unless you've built the application to be database-agnostic and have already verified that it works correctly with one of the database engines that you're considering, porting it to another database would be a major undertaking.  Plus, different databases work differently so it is entirely possible that you'd get different results testing against Oracle.

Comment: @JustinCave the reason I am not inclined towards an installer is because the databases like derby and HSQL are very portable. I can pass along my DB to another developer and he/she will be ready in minutes with a basic DB with all schemas. Installing the DB like Oracle express edition is not what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience try to use H2 database in Oracle Mode. It generally does  come close to Oracle DB style. But custom functions and stored procedures you have to create ALIAS to let the H2 know that this is a custom function or procedure and this is the Java class for that. Also if you have VIEWS and stuff you can still create those as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Derby is a great choice for unit testing.

However, Derby is quite strict about its adherence to SQL standards.

If your database operations (table schemas, SQL statements, etc.) are very compliant with the SQL standard, you'll probably find it straightforward to run your tests against Derby.

But if you've used Oracle-specific vendor extensions in your schema or SQL, you'll find that Derby generally doesn't implement those Oracle extensions.

Also, stored procedure languages in particular vary widely from vendor to vendor, so your Oracle stored procedures may not be accepted by Derby.